# LWJGL Some textures not working

Tags: opengl, lwjgl

I'm trying to make a game with LWJGL.
SO I have my camera set up correctly and now I want to make a House with a working door.
The Front of the House is Textured but when I try du put the Texture on the door it doesn't work.

Main class

```
Texture wall_2 = loadTexture("wall_2");
Texture door = loadTexture("door");
```

And inside the Gameloop

```
        glLoadIdentity();
        cam.setView();
        House_Test.drawHouse(wall_2,door);
        Ground.drawGround(ground);
```

House_Test:

```
    public static void drawHouse(Texture tex, Texture tür){

    walls.draw(tex);
    roof.draw(tex);

    door.draw(tür);

     }
```

And the draw method of the door:

```
    public static void draw(Texture door) {  
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    GL11.glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        door.bind();
        glTexCoord2f(0,0);glVertex3f(-2,2, -15);
        glTexCoord2f(0,1);glVertex3f(-2,-3, -15);
        glTexCoord2f(1,1);glVertex3f(2,-3, -15);
        glTexCoord2f(1,0);glVertex3f(2,2, -15);

    glEnd();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your texture is not getting properly bound. The `glBindTexture()` call (which I assume `door.bind()` eventually calls) cannot be called between `glBegin()` and `glEnd()`. If you call `glGetError()` it should return an invalid operation error in this case. Move the call to `door.bind()` to before the call to `glBegin()`.

Also, the call to `glClear()` needs to be moved outside of `glBegin()`/`glEnd()`, too. Although, if you do that, the walls will get drawn, then cleared (erased), then the door will get drawn. So you probably want to put the `glClear()` before all drawing.

Comment: Thank you :D It's is working now but the textures color is not what it should be.(Cause now I have a blue door and that is not like it is in the texture ^^)

Comment: You should post a new question about that and include the code you're using to upload the textures.